# SQL Server Hex to BIGINT Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to convert Hexadecimal value into BIGINT and again covert back same  value to Hexadecimal format getting different value but getting different results when using below conversation method

For example:

Hexadecimal value: `0x00000000F515C6BC`

Hex to BIGINT:

```
Cast(0x00000000F515C6BC as Big int)
```

O/p- `4111845052`

BIGINT to Hex-

```
Convert (varbinary(8),4111845052)
```

O/p- `0xA000001BCC615F5`

PS: Hex to BIGINT is giving me result 4111845052 but when converting same number to Hex format it's giving output as `0xA000001BCC615F5` which is not same as original value (`0x00000000F515C6BC`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `CAST` 4111845052 as a `bigint`:

```
select Convert (varbinary(8),cast(4111845052 as bigint))
```

The value 4111845052 is being implicitly converting to a `varbinary` as the default implicit conversion to an `int` is not possible. It seems that as the value is found within a function converting to `varbinary` it implicitly converts it to a varbinary as this is the best indicator of the type. You can confirm this by running the following which will give you the same result:

```
select Convert (varbinary(8), 4111845052)
select Convert (varbinary(8), cast(4111845052 as varbinary))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response . I tried but getting same result with both the statements .

Comment: `select Convert (varbinary(8),cast(4111845052 as bigint))` returns 0x00000000F515C6BC - your original value. The other two statements return 0x0A000001BCC615F5 - the value you were querying.